# How to set Preferred Service Name to Spark driver on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

I want to setup Ingres to access the Spark Web UI which deployed on Kubernetes cluster.

I created Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: some-test-job-v1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-private
  rules:
    - host: some-test-job-v1.spark.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service: 
              name: some-test-job-v1-ui-svc
              port:
                number: 4040
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - some-test-job-v1.spark.example.com
      secretName: some-test-job-v1-spark-example-com
```

The problem is Spark [generates service name](https://jaceklaskowski.github.io/spark-kubernetes-book/DriverServiceFeatureStep/#service-name) as `spark-[randomServiceId]-driver-svc`, so we cant configure Ingress with specified constant service name, like 'some-test-job-v1-ui-svc'.
There is a described possibility to set [Preferred Service Name](https://jaceklaskowski.github.io/spark-kubernetes-book/DriverServiceFeatureStep/#preferredServiceName), but what property should I pass?
Tried `spark.kubernetes.resourceNamePrefix: "test"`, but it still creating with `serviceRandomId`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't seem to set that property, see related code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/KubernetesConf.scala#L91) and [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/KubernetesConf.scala#L259).

However since Spark 3.2 you can implement custom feature step classes that can execute code after the [Driver service is created](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/DriverServiceFeatureStep.scala#L74) so you could implement code that would save the service name to a config map for example. Later you could use the value from the config map to initialize your Ingress object.
See `spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.featureSteps` property in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html.

Note that this is just an idea, I haven't tried it myself.